# Build documentation for older version before .readthedocs.yaml was added to repo

Tags: read-the-docs

I am importing a project to read the docs; I have a series of git tags representing older versions of the library; which I would like to have docs generated for those versions as well.  The problem is that there is no `.readthedocs.yaml` file in the repo when that tag was placed.

Normally in this case I would put some of the relevant settings in web interface, which clearly states those settings would be ignored with the presence of a `.readthedocs.yaml` file; but my config file does have a `pre_build` task

```yaml
version: 2

build:
  os: "ubuntu-22.04"
  tools:
    python: "3.10"
  jobs:
    pre_build:
      - doxygen ./doc/doxygen/doxygen.conf

sphinx:
  builder: html
  configuration: doc/conf.py

python:
  install:
    - requirements: doc/requirements.txt
```

Is there a way I can build documentation for past git tags using the "current" config file?

Comment: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/#versioning-documentation

Comment: Unfortunately, that link doesn't work in my case as there is no `.readthedocs.yaml` file present in those older versions of the project https://cubeupload.com/im/j9ac9k/ScreenShot20220522at.png

Comment: That configuration is possible through the web UI, no .yaml needed. We do it for Pyramid.

Comment: unfortunately there does not appear to be a way to specify a pre_build step in the webui, or to specify a doc/requirements.txt that isn't already in the repo at the time the git tag was made.

Comment: I'd recommend you build your documentation from new branches instead of old tags. Instead of building from tag `3.0`, you can create a branch off `3.0` tag called `3.x` and add the `.readthedocs.yaml` into that branch. After that, you can go to Read the Docs and enable that version

Comment: That's the conclusion I came to; not a deal breaker by any means.  Thanks for posting!